# Error in using statement in connecting mysql in my java project

Tags: java, mysql

[screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExWfC.png)I want to use statement in connecting mysql and java database, but the code is giving me errors, I want to know where did I go wrong and how I should do it without getting errore

```
try{
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sms","root","");
                 Statement st= (Statement)conn.createStatement();
                 String sql= "select * from user_login";
       }
           catch(Exception e){
               
           }![this is the screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo8Yo.png)
```

[image: this is the declaration of the program]

I tried using this[image: declaration]

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of or links to code. SO has a code formatter so code can easiliy be embedded in your question.

Comment: `the code is giving me errors,` That statement should always be followed by the actual error message, as we have no way of knowing what it is unless you show us  ;-) To troubleshoot, you need to print out the error in the `catch` clause, not "swallow" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so to do JDBC with MySql you need 4 things

1. Driver Class
2. Connection URL
3. Username
4. Password

Assuming you have already created the database, with name `database_name` and table `data` that has 3 columns as `id`, `first_name` & `last_name`

Connection and showing the data in as follows:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
class ConnectionToDatabase{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name","username","Pa$$word");
      Statement statement = connnection.createStatement();
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from data");
      while(resultSet.next()){
        System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3));
        connection.close();  
      }  
    }catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
  }
}
```

And of course, you can use Spring Boot, where a file named `application.properties` exists inside `java.resources`, you can specify the connection as - (Copied from Spring docs)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=databaseusername
spring.datasource.password=databasepassword
```